# Class has no 'objects' member in django

Tags: python, django, django-views

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Destination
def index(request):
    boards = Destination.objects.all()
    boards_names = list()
    for Destination in boards:
     boards_names.append(Destination.destinationtext)
     response_html = '<br>'.join(boards_names)
     return HttpResponse(response_html)
```

I have written this code following just for practice of django framework but I am getting the following errors through pylint :

```
E1101:Class 'Destination' has no 'objects' member
E0601:Using variable 'Destination' before assignment
```

Comment: You wrote `for Destination in ...` so you have *overwritten* the reference to the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two different issues, and not just one as you say:

`E1101:Class 'Destination' has no 'objects' member`: Is a *warning*
that occurs because `pylint` doesn't know about our special Django variables. A pylint plugin like [`pylint-django`](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint-django) might do the trick.

`E0601:Using variable 'Destination' before assignment`: In the for loop in your code you defined a variable called `Destination`. This is not only bad practice because python variables need to be in `lowercase_underscore` but **it overrides the `Destination` class**, and that's what is causing this error. You probably wanted to do something like this:

```
for d in boards:
# Or:
for destination in boards:
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Pylint: this is a real error, since it treats `Destination` as a *local* variable due to the `for` loop.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem the error is `Destination` has no variable `objects`, which refers to the line `Destination.objects.all()`, two lines before the local variable with the same name is created.

Comment: no, that is a Pylint *hint*, but it will not error if you run it.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote in your view:

```
for Destination in boards:
    # ...
```

This means that Python sees `Destination` as a *local* variable, a local variable that you *use* before it is assigned.

You can rename the variable in the loop to solve the problem, but actually you can make it more elegant and faster here by using `.values_list(..)`:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Destination

def index(request):
    response_html = '<br>'.join(
        Destination.objects.values_list('destinationtext', flat=True)
    )
    return HttpResponse(response_html)
```

Nevertheless, I'm still not convinced that this solves the matter, since the `destinationtext` could contain HTML, which then will mix up in the response. Usually it is better to use templates.

Comment: The error occurs 2 lines before OP declares that variable. It is a problem, but it's not _the_ problem.

Comment: @NonameSL: of course that is the problem. What do you think "Using variable 'Destination' before assignment" means?

Comment: it appears both of us are right, as OP gets two errors: `E1101:Class 'Destination' has no 'objects' member` and `E0601:Using variable 'Destination' before assignment`

Comment: @NonameSL: but those are two PyLint *warnings*. Pylint complains about a lot that will not raise errors, it simply wants to improve code quality.

Comment: True, but the title of the question is `Class has no 'objects' member in django`, and this is the error that OP thinks he got. You are correct, but I'm just referencing to the error OP thought they got and the second error which as you say isn't just a warning, is an error.