# 'Post' object has no attribute 'comments'?

Tags: django, django-models, model, django-templates, django-views

I'm creating a basic blog webapp using django. The app starts without an error but when I click on drafts an error come up with **AttributeError at /drafts 'Post' object has no attribute 'comments'**

I've tried by putting `comments = models.Manager()` but then another error comes up saying **Manager isn't accessible via post instances**

my models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User',on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True,null=True)
    # objects = models.Manager()
    # comments = models.Manager() 
    
    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now
        self.save()
        
    def approve_comments(self):
        return self.comments.filter(approved_comment=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blogapp:post_detail',kwargs={'pk':self.pk})

    def __str__(self): 
        return self.title

class Comment(models.Model):
    
    post = models.ForeignKey('blogapp.Post',on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    text = models.TextField(max_length=264)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    approved_comment = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def approve(self):
        self.approved_comment = True
        self.save()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blogapp:post_list')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

my drafts view look something like

```
class DraftListView(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
    login_url = '/login/'
    redirect_field_name = 'blogapp/post_list.html'
    model = Post

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Post.objects.filter(published_date__isnull=True).order_by('create_date')
```

I'm using 'comments' variable in another html and views file. And the same error arise with 'objects' while executing the line

```
Post.objects.filter(published_date__isnull=True).order_by('create_date')
```

in my views.py file

Comment: The error indicates that you likely created a `Post` *object* with the name `Post`.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this steps:

1 .- You must define the model `Comment`

2 .- The `Comment` model must define a **foreign key** to `Post`

3 .- This **foreign key** needs the attribute `related_name` in order to be accessible via Post model usign the word `comments`

+Info: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name

Comment: Hey! I had already made the Comment class in models.py I didn't include it in my question as I thought it won't matter. Check my models.py But it's still showing the error-  'Post' attribute has no 'comments' member. Please help

Comment: You don't define related name so by default the name is not comments, is **comment_set**

Comment: It's still not working. check my comment on other answer. Help

Comment: Put the stacktrace, it will be useful

Answer (score 0):

use `related_name` attribute
and you don't need to use `'blogapp.Post'` if it is in same file, but just `Post` instead

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='comments', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

in case if it is on different app/models file, use `blogapp.models.Post` instead

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(blogapp.models.Post, related_name='comments', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

Comment: It is still not working, the error is same -Instance of 'Post' has no 'comments' member and Class Post has no 'objects' member.

Comment: is error exist in your browser or your IDE? maybe you can check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51828667/class-has-no-objects-member-in-django) or this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135263/class-has-no-objects-member)

Answer (score 0):

```
def approve_comments(self):
    return self.**comments**.filter(approved_comment=True)
```

Hello, hackerWorld I think error is here in approve_comments you return the comments which is not attribute of your Post class.